# corrupted bashrc and bashprofile

Tags: shell, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, bash

hi i made some mistake in bashrc and bash_profile .the problem is not working properly . i discovered when i installed phantomjs  . it has been installed properly , but when i executed

```
               phantomjs --version
```

the output was

```
                 bash: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs: No such file or directory
```

but when i checked it located in /usr/local/bin/.if u need any details here  i will post it

Is there any way to delete the bashrc and bash_profile file and install them freshly . i have also tried replacing with /etc/skel where the bashrc and bash_profile

Comment: Are you having problems logging in due to the problems in the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`? If not, just `mv .bashrc bashrc.bad` and `mv .bash_profile bash_profile.bad` (assuming you want to save them for reference).

Comment: is there any way to repair or install from fresh start

Comment: It depends upon what you had in them. Over time, I would not know what kinds of environment settings, etc, that you have put in them that you require. So you'd probably need to go through the existing files, find the actual error, and just remove that portion that introduced the error. The ideal case would be if you maintain system backups (which I do regularly) and restore from the most recent working version.

Comment: What makes you think that something in `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile` would cause the `No such file or directory` error you saw? That message is telling you a very specific file (since it was specified by full path name, and thus not subject to any `PATH` searches or anything) does not exist (or maybe that you don't have permission to access it, but that usually produces `Permission denied` instead).

Answer (score -1):

Dacci il risultato di
                        ls -l /usr/local/bin/
e poi vediamo

Comment: Please post in english, but even in english this should be a *comment*, it's certainly not an answer.

Comment: total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 57 Aug 28 14:25 phantomjs -> /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.0-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs
@user2706318